# Canvas or Swing for simple board game in Java?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, awt

So I am trying to build a very basic prototype of a board game in java. The view for the board of the game itself will basically only show figures and other elements, there will be no way to interact with this view at all, there are other views which will be programmed with swing, that are used to interact with the game. Should I still use swing to build a chess board like game board with layered panes or should I use the rather outdated awt canvas? Is there another possible candidate which wouldn't be too much overkill?

I guess swing would still be the way to got, it just seems so counter intuitive to use it for something that just shows a few images with different layers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Carelessly mixing Swing and AWT components may produce [unexpected results](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Comment: (I didn't downvote, but) the question is very unspecific. The difference between `Canvas` and a `JPanel` is negligible regarding *what and how you are implementing it*. Due to the points that trashgod mentioned, you should hardly *ever* use a `Canvas` in Swing. Usually, you do custom painting on a `JPanel`. But the actual painting code will basically be the same (and you don't *have* to use some fancy layered panes in Swing - you can just draw on a `JPanel` like you would on a `Canvas`...)

Answer (score 0):

A game should have a game loop, so Swing would not be the best way how to do it. Better use `Canvas` with `Thread`, or a `JPanel` with a `Timer` for this.

Comment: I'm not sure if I would agree, it's basically a prototype for a board game so there is no need for animation and it takes quite a while until the board needs to change.

Comment: If OP wants to make a real time strategy game on the board with animations, probably yes. If not, it will be an overkill to implement a game loop.